# Not finding 'weightedMean' object for numFun using kNN in VIM package for R

Tags: r, knn, imputation

I'm getting an error stating that the 'weightedMean' argument is not found for the 'numFun' parameter in the kNN imputation function within the VIM R package. I'm attempting to impute data in a fairly large dataset, and I want to use kNN with 5 neighbors using weighted means.

Here is my code:

```
df.imputed <- kNN(df, variable = c(...), dist_var = c(...), numFun = weightedMean, k = 5, weightDist = TRUE, trace = TRUE, imp_var = TRUE)
```

And the exact error is:

Error in args(numFun) : object 'weightedMean' not found

Based on the documentation (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VIM/VIM.pdf page 29) it seems like this should work.

Comment: You should load the library `library(laeken)` prior to calling the function.

Comment: That was it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try  put  this way numFun = weighted.mean,
at least worked for me